# Failed to fetch -- apt-get update, “Temporary failure resolving …” & unable to locate package ERROR

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates

Good day,

**NOTE:** I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 on VM Box

I get the following error: apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error.

I tried literally every "fix" I can per this user group and others on the net.  I still have the same error.

help please;

Comment: Can you access any other internet sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to the machine settings. Go to the `NETWORK` option, and select the option `Bridged`. Then hit the Advanced dropdown and select `Allow All` in the dropdown Promiscuous.

I had this same problem and doing what I said above solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because Apt is unable to connect to the website you listed as the upstream Apt repository that you are installing packages from.  This issue is on your end, unless the upstream you are using is having a REALLY bad day.

Does the VM have internet access? If you run "ping google.com", what do you get?

If there is internet, check your /etc/apt/sources.list file, to ensure that the internet domains named as sources are valid.  See `man sources.list` for details on the format, but the second word (after 'deb') must be a valid URL.

Comment: Ping a site you know works not google.com many google sites do not respond to ping.

Comment: @david I just tested to be sure, ping google.com worked great.